# Get a long value from an NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, long-integer

I need to get a `long` value from an `NSString`.

For example, I have this:

```
NSString *test = @"5437128";
```

and I need :

```
long myLong = 5437128;
```

How I can get this `long` value from the `NSString`?

Thank you, it will help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the NSScanner like in the following code:

```
  unsigned x;

[[NSScanner scannerWithString: s2] scanHexInt: &x];
```

when typing the scanHexInt stop at scan and see yourself which one you need - there are many possibilities to get values from strings....

You might want to use `scanlonglong`... having declared your variable as long

Answer (score 15):

```
long longVariable = [test longLongValue];
```

See [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) documentation..

Comment: Note that `long` cannot be used as an identifier.

Comment: @Bavarious Yes...didn't noticed that..just used the code segment in question..will edit now..Thanks for noting..

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
long number = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:string] longValue];
[numberFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

i use the following in case you don't want to lose the fractions value of your number

```
double x =[stringValue doubleValue];
```

instead of

```
 double x = [stringValue  longLongValue];
```

if we assume that we have the following string value 
and we want to convert it to double we have 2 ways

```
NSString * stringValue = @"31.211529225111";
way #1 
    double x = [stringValue  longLongValue];
result will be  :  x = 31

way #2 
    double x =[stringValue doubleValue];
result will be  :  x = 31.211529225111001
```